# AttributeError: '..' object has no attribute '..' , but it has

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```
Builder.load_string(oneplayer)

class OnePlayer(Screen):
    
    def gago(self):
        self.ids.title.text = "5"
```

Where:

```
oneplayer = """

< OnePlayer > :
    
    FloatLayout:
        
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex("#FEE4A6")
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        
        Button:
            text: "Gago"
            
            size_hint: 0.1 , 0.1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5 , "center_y": 0.1 }
            
            on_press:
                root.gago()
            
        
        Label:
            
            id: title
            
            text: "1"
            font_size: "40sp"
            font_name: "united-kingdom/United Kingdom DEMO.otf"
            valign: "center"
            halign: "center"
            
            color: hex("#586B8F")
            outline_color: hex("#00EAFF")
            outline_width: dp(2.5)
            background_normal: ''
            
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5 , "center_y": 0.70 }
"""
```

It always give me an error even though my `OnePlayer` class has an `gago()`:

```
kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'OnePlayer' object has no attribute 'gago'
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but spaces inside the `<>` are significant. `< OnePlayer >` is not the same as `<OnePlayer>`.

Comment: Thanks but I already figure it out , The Problem is importing of classes